# ССП однородное?

Tags: синтаксический-разбор, ссп, однородные-члены

Проверьте, правильно ли я выбрала из текста предложения ССП однородного состава:

1.Да он как навесит на себя две катушки со связью, да вещмешок на горб водрузит.

2.Феликс слушал говорок доктора, и виделись ему серые пятна отопревших от пара гнездышек над входом вонючей бердской казармы.

сомневаюсь насчет 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Т.к во втором примере в частях сложного предложения имеется значение одновременности,что выражено соответствием видовременных форм глаголов-сказуемых, это позволяет отнести ССП к однородному типу.

Comment: 1 -  я так понимаю, тоже верно?

Comment: Да,  1-ое предложение тоже верно.

Comment: спасибо вам !!!